# Part of a dentist's chair

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the name of the part of the dentist's chair used for pouring water into a glass so the patient can wash his/her mouth?

Comment: Somebody should ask a dentist or dental hygienist. I think of it as a 'spitbowl'

Comment: @Mitch: No, that's where you spit *after* you rinse, I sure hope that your dentist doesn't fill pour into your cup *from* the contents of the spitbowl. ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: hmmm...yes...I thought of the whole assembly (the spigot and bowl as one thing and named the bowl).

Comment: Many American dental setups have no chair-attached water-pouring-thing, but instead have a water-bottle + pump + hose + spigot-on-handpiece + suction device attached to the dental chair.  The dentist or hygenist presses one handpiece-lever to squirt water into patient's mouth, then another lever to suction the water back out after patient swishes the water.  No sink or bowl on or near the chair.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called a Cuspidor.  The entire unit together with the facet and the sink.

I'm a dentist :-) so I know.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly specialized *water dispenser*? Maybe call it a "dentist's water dispenser"?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking about the *faucet* and not the basin, so that's what I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard my dentist call it a *spout*, as in "Now you can fill that cup with water from the *spout*."

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it doesn't actually answer the question. Yours comes from a dentist and makes sense, therefore +1